# probability: Combinations and Permutations

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

An urn contains 4 red balls, 5 black balls and 6 white balls. Two are withdrawn at random without replacement. Find the probability that:
a)  Both are red;

4/15 *3/14 = 2/35

b)  One is red and the other is black;

4/15*5/14 + 5/15 *4/14 = 4/21

c)  Exactly one is red

4/15*11/14 + 11/15*4/14 = 44/105

I want to know  how they solve b and c ? what's the formula used to calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (b), you say that for one to be red and the other black, one of these two (mutually exclusive) events had to happen:

- First one is red ($\frac4{15}$) then second is black ($\frac{5}{14}$) or ...
- First one is black ($\frac5{15}$) then second is red($\frac{4}{14}$)

and you add these probabilities to get the probability that either of these events happen.

For (c) the method is the same, but instead of "the other is black" substitute "the other is non-red."